# .htaccess redirect if number is lower (or bigger) than X

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

If we want to redirect, for example:

```
/node/id=XXX
```

to another site, but only if XXX is smaller than some number (for example, 5000), how can i do it? I tried with regular expressions but i cannot get it working.

Thanks!

Comment: Regular expressions are not really the right tool for this to begin with ... You will want to match either up to three digits, or a digit in the range of 1 to 4 with exactly three further digits behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
.*id=(\d{1,3}\D|[1-4]\d{3}\D)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!